# Applet starts but the size or color of the background does not follow the code

Tags: java, applet

Here is the code:

```
package guimodule; 

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {

    public void SetUp() {
        size (500,100);
        background(0,0,0);
    }

    public void draw() {

    }
}
```

Comment: figured the answer: the name of the method is written with convention of a class "SetUp". It should be "setup"

Comment: If you think this information would be helpful to others, write it out as an answer and accept it.